# Parse a JSON string stored in a constant in ionic 3

Tags: android, json, angular, parsing, ionic-framework

How can I parse json string in ionic 3.My requirement is simple i.e just parse the json stored in a constant and show it in a slider having previous and next button in ionic.Just help me out with parsing the data and store it in the array.I have no prior experience in ionic and angular.

Code I have tried:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

//////this is the json format.
const questions={
  "setId": 1,
  "setName": "Set-A",
  "totalQuestions": 3,
  "markPerQuestion": 1,
  "totalDuration": 10,
  "questions": [
      {
          "questionId": 1,
          "questionName": "What is the term used for describing the judgmental part of problem solving?",
          "questionInstruction": "Select Correct Answer",
          "questionAnswer": "a",
          "img": "",
          "questionOptions": [
              {
                  "optionId": "a",
                  "optionValue": "Heuristic"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "b",
                  "optionValue": "Critical"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "c",
                  "optionValue": "Value based"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "d",
                  "optionValue": "Analytical"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "e",
                  "optionValue": "None of the above"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "questionId": 2,
          "questionName": "Decision support programs are designed to help managers make:",
          "questionInstruction": "Select Correct Answer",
          "questionAnswer": "d",
          "img": "",
          "questionOptions": [
              {
                  "optionId": "a",
                  "optionValue": "vacation schedules"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "b",
                  "optionValue": "budget projections"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "c",
                  "optionValue": "All of the above"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "d",
                  "optionValue": "business decisions"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "e",
                  "optionValue": "None of the above"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "questionId": 3,
          "questionName": "What was originally called the imitation game by its creator?",
          "questionInstruction": "Select Correct Answer",
          "questionAnswer": "b",
          "img": "",
          "questionOptions": [
              {
                  "optionId": "a",
                  "optionValue": "Cybernetics"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "b",
                  "optionValue": "The Turing Test"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "c",
                  "optionValue": "LISP"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "d",
                  "optionValue": "The Logic Theorist"
              },
              {
                  "optionId": "e",
                  "optionValue": "None of the above"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
};

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.parsejsondata();
  }

  parsejsondata(){
    const userStr = JSON.stringify(questions);
    JSON.parse(userStr, (key, value) => {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value.toUpperCase();
      }
      console.log(JSON.parse(value));
      return value;
    });
  }
}
```

it is throwing a error:

> main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status
>   of 500 (Internal Server Error) (index):1 Refused to execute script
>   from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

Comment: I am not entirely sure your error is related to this code...

Comment: in the console it is showing this error.I am not sure that if my code is correct or not